# Blocking a jenkins task until all downstream tasks complete?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Is there any way in jenkins to block a given task on all its downstream tasks? I have a series of functional test phases, and each needs to run against a server after deployment. The server should *not* be updated while tests are running, however.

So I have jobs:

`A -> B -> C`

I need `A` to block until `C` completes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the Advanced Project Options, "Block build when downstream project is building" option for project A.  I believe that will prevent multiple instances of A running until all downstream projects (ie, B and C) have completed.

Answer (score 9):

As Jason mentioned the setting is under the "Advanced Project Options" section and looks like the following:

[image: Block build when downstream project is building]

Comment: Note that its slightly difficult to find because you'll need to click the "Advanced" button in order for the above set of options to display. This was available on Jenkins ver. 1.458 for me.